# Notepad++: extract parts of text from a xml format (reg exp)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a xml format file and i want to keep only particular nodes of it and delete all the rest, so i just will have what i need.

The xml can be like this:

```
<xml>
    <worker>
        <name>test</name>
        <age>33</age>
        <job>programmer</job>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <name>test2</name>
        <age>41</age>
        <job>project manager</job>
    </worker>
        ...
</xml>
```

Result needed is:

```
<age>33</age>
<age>41</age>
```

Comment: Tell me if I'm right: you want to keep only (and all) `<age>...</age>` in a file.

Comment: my mistake, sorry...

Comment: @Toto, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Search menu > Mark
- Find: `^\h*<age>\d+</age>`
- Check `Mark lines`
- <kbd>Find all</kbd>
- Search menu > Bookmark
- Remove unmarked lines